# Issue with converting Javascript Date

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have a string "2014-01-27". Now how can it be converted into "**2014-01-27T00:00:00.0000000**" ?
Is that a valid date format avail in javascript ?

Comment: `new Date("2014-01-27").toISOString()` is at least close, showing milliseconds instead of nanoseconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "2014-01-27T00:00:00.0000000" ? Is that a valid date format avail in javascript ?

Yes, but…

[ECMA-262 says](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15) that where an ISO 8601-like string is missing  the time zone (e.g. 2014-01-27T00:00:00.0000000) then it is assumed to be UTC. However, if you pass a string like that to Date.parse, some browsers treat it as local and some as UTC (and some, like IE 8, won't parse it at all, even with a time zone).

To avoid that, manually parse the string and create a UTC date:

```
function parseYMDasUTC(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(Date.UTC(b[0],--b[1],b[2]));
}

console.log(parseYMDasUTC("2014-01-27")); // Mon Jan 27 2014 08:00:00 GMT+0800
```